# How to use method injection with App::call in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, laravel-5, service-provider

I am using Laravel 5.2 and wrote my own Service Provider. I want to inject a *Request* object into the register method.

The base problem is that I want to call different service container depending on a special request param - all the service container implementing the same interface/contract of course.

The error message I am getting is:

```
ReflectionException in Container.php line 559:
Function registerService() does not exist
```

My service provider looks like that:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Contracts\Extractor;

class ExtractorServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Indicates if loading of the provider is deferred.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $defer = true;

    /**
     * Available services for channels
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $availableServices = ['AExtractor', 'ZExtractor'];

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->call('registerService');
    }

    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @return void
     */
    protected function registerService(Request $request)
    {
        $tag = DB::table('channels')->where('id', $request->channel)->value('tag')->first()->tag;

        $selectedExtractor = $tag . 'Extractor';
        $extractor = 'AExtractor';

        if(in_array($selectedExtractor, $this->availableServices)) {
            $extractor = $selectedExtractor;
        }

        $this->app->bind('App\Contracts\Extractor', "App\\Helpers\\{$extractor}");
    }

    /**
     * Get the services provided by the provider.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function provides()
    {
        return [Extractor::class];
    }
}
```

How can I use `$this->app->call('registerService');` to call my `registerService` function and inject the *Request* object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you're calling `App:call` in a wrong way: you have to specify the object on which you want to call the method and the method, like this :

```
$this->app->call( [ $this, 'registerService' ] );
```

Comment: Lovely, that works! Now there is problem with the `DB` facade not found but it finally calls the `registerService` method. Cheers!

Comment: @codedge :  for the facade probably you have to include use DB; on top of your file

Comment: Yes, that was it! Thanks!

Comment: Additional parameters can be passed to the `registerService` method by passing an array of parameters to the second argument of `call()`. The array can be numerically indexed to provide positional arguments, or key/value pairs where the key references an argument name.